# Angular 1.2.6 app works until I enable Batarang 0.4.3

Tags: angularjs, batarang

Here's the error I get when I enable Batarang:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp.services due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at assertArg (http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:1360:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:1370:3)
    at annotate (http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:3016:5)
    at Object.$provide.(anonymous function) [as service] (<anonymous>:693:26)
    at http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:3621:37
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:302:11)
    at loadModules (http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:3608:5)
    at http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:3615:40
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp.services&p1=E…0at%20http%3A%2F%2Fhost.local%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3615%3A40
    at http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:3642:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:302:11)
    at loadModules (http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:3608:5)
    at http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:3615:40
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:302:11)
    at loadModules (http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:3608:5)
    at createInjector (http://host.local/lib/angular/angular.js:3548:11)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…or%20(http%3A%2F%2Fhost.local%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3548%3A11)
```

Before this there are no errors and the app works fine. Are there things I need to include to use Batarang? Several of the most recent comments in the Chrome Web Store about Batarang are that it doesn't work now, maybe due to ng-route.

Comment: I've been using Batarang a lot with 1.2.9 until latest lately with no issue. Does using a newer version of angular fix the issue?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing exact the same issue! How did you fix this?

Comment: I didn't fix it! I got another side project and haven't touched angular for a month.

Comment: possible duplicate of [batarang Chrome extension for AngularJS appears broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506526/batarang-chrome-extension-for-angularjs-appears-broken)