# batarang Chrome extension for AngularJS appears broken

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, batarang

(I added this post to a long series at Github of similar/recent experiences. I'm hoping someone here has an answer.)

Oh, good, I'm not just stoopid.

Trying to learn Angular on my own, from a book. When it calls out the use of batarang to show scope and models for a small sample script, and I fire up batarang, all I get is 'Scopes' over 'Scope()' on the left, and 'Models' over 'Select a scope to view its models.' and an 'Enable Inspector' button below that. Yes, I checked the box on the  'Enable' tab.

None of it seems to do anything.

On the 'Models' tab, clicking 'Scope()' (per the instructions on the 'Help' tab) does nothing, nor does clicking anything else. Weirdly, under the Options tab, I can check Show applications, Show bindings and Show scopes, These make pretty (and pretty useless) boxes around sections of the script's resulting page, above the dev tools pane, but all the checks clear as soon as I click another tab, like 'Models' (where nothing is working, still), and then come back to the Options tab.

Says I'm on "1.0.2 debilitating-awesomeness"...which is the AngularJS version, I suppose, but really describes batarang so far.

PS: I watched the video (http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/07/introducing-angularjs-batarang.html) but it was useless, as it assumes the thing is already working.

Oh, yea, Win7Pro64SvPk1, Chrome 34.0.1847.131 m 'is up to date'

Hope the other recommended tools work better, or at least work.

Meanwhile, can anyone confirm the status of batarang? Sure seems a lot of people have a dead extension.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report

Comment: i just tried and the new `AngularJS Inspector` works for me

Answer (score 15):

Try "[AngularJS Batarang (Stable)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek)" by "spencer.leland". It works for me.

I use AngularJS 1.3.6 and Chrome Ver. 39

Comment: Batarang maintainer here - that plugin is not supported by the official Batarang team (and so bugs there won't be fixed).  The latest version (0.8.7) is working fine.

Answer (score 4):

The last release of Batarang was over 10 months ago.  It looks like it is no longer supported and does not work with Angular 1.2.x

Comment: That's not completely true. I was using it a few weeks ago with 1.2.3, but I have not tried since I upgraded to 1.2.15. I found batarang was not all that helpful in the end, because any time the page had performance problems enough to warrant using it, it was so slow as to be completely useless. Also the thing seems like it might have some leaks, the longer I would let it run the more unresponsive Chrome would be. Often had to kill -9 chrome threads in console.

Comment: I don't remember when 1.2 was released but that last release of Batarang, according to GitHub, was 10 months ago.  I find it a useful tool but haven't missed it.  The author, Brian Ford, is now part of the core AngularJS team at Google.  You can contact him via Google+ or Twitter if you're interested in asking about a future release.

Comment: Thanks all. I'm covering new ground without any 'live' developers around me to check with...again. Good to have this virtual community to maintain and improve my perpsective.

Comment: Reading the comments/reviews on the Plugin at the chrome web store, it seems it is no longer properly functional at Angular 1.3.

Comment: I think it is important for authors of an open source project to explain that something is beta or that it is stable release.  Seems like that is what is being missed here.  So if you are using beta you should figure that it might lack stability.  If you are using stable release and it has bugs.., shame on the Author for not updating the version notes.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that the stable version (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable, version 0.4.3) works fine, with Angular 1.3.13 and the Ionic framework.

On the "batarang stable" page they even warn that this version works and the newer version doesn't.

I tried the newer version (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang, 0.7.4) and it didn't work indeed, half of the options were gone from the UI.

Answer (score 2):

I had issues with Batarang while running a page as a file with the `file:///` protocol. Putting things inside Nginx and running the page from that webserver solved my problem.

This probably applies to Apache and any other web server. I am running Batarang 0.8.6 on Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit).

So, Batarang IS working in the latest version.
[image: Batarang working in browser]

[image: Batarang in Developer Tools]

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! An easy way to serve your local files using a webserver is using python: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8081`