# Batarang on Chrome mobile devtools doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, batarang

I'm debuggin a mobile application using Chrome devtools, I can inspect the device, network tab, console tab, etc are working fine, I can see the batarang tab AngularJS, when I click Enable the page is reload on the chrome mobile tab but the batarang tab don't show any kind of information.

Do you have any idea?

[image]
<sub>(source: [vpsnotas.com](https://www.vpsnotas.com/images/batarang.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though Batarang hasn't been updated to be compatible with the latest versions of AngularJS.  Appears to be a duplicate of: [batarang Chrome extension for AngularJS appears broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506526/batarang-chrome-extension-for-angularjs-appears-broken)

Answer (score 0):

Does the console show any errors or anything?  That would be the first place I would look, as it will normally point you in the right direction of the issue.

I recently ran into an issue with loading Batarang on an angular app that I know was previous working.  The console was throwing an $injector:modulerr error and the issue turned out to be with the ng-strict-di directive on the ng-app.  After removing the ng-strict-di directive from the ng-app, the Batarang extension works fine.